# Не поднимаются интеграционные тесты используя Circle CI & Docker

Tags: java, docker, circleci

Пытаюсь настроить Circle CI, хочу чтобы поднимались интеграциооные тесты с помощью докера. В итоге вот такая вот ошибка на гите

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

2019-09-20 16:02:38.121 ERROR 247 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@1451bb2b] to prepare test instance [com.impltech.ua.bot_job.olx.mapper.MapperSubscriptionToSubscriptionTempTest@33b40d3b]
```

Ямл файл вот такой:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk-node-browsers
    working_directory: ~/repo
    environment:
      MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
      DRIVER-CLASS-NAME: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
      DATABASE_URL: jdbc:tc:postgresql://ignore:5432/ignore
      DATABASE_USER:
      DATABASE_PASSWORD:
    steps:
      - checkout

        # start proprietary DB using private Docker image
      - setup_remote_docker

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: mvn dependency:go-offline

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}

      - run: mvn integration-test

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: yarn install

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      - run: yarn test
```

Скорее всего я не прописал какие то докер команды, по этому этот вариант не работает

Answer (score 1):

Не прописаны докер команды , ну и не стоит галочка , а также отсутствует верхний элемент в разрезе

Comment: ну в этом и была догадка, можешь пожалуйста написать какие, а то я искал и плоховато с поиском, если можно то подробнее а то очень застрял

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: а ты посмотри контейнеры, в которые инспектишь , там сразу очевидно станет
я бы еще STDIN  приклеил

Comment: понимал бы я докер - таких вопросов не задавал, но я в нем новичек, а задание нужно сделать срочно, ну ладно буду дальше разбираться

Comment: docker run, docker build достаточно?